# Probability Concepts

Tags: probability

Which of these numbers cannot be a probability?

a) $-0.00001$

b) $0.5$

c) $1.001$

d) $0$

e) $1$

f) $20\%$

Probability can either be expressed in percentages, decimals, proper fractions or numbers between 0 to 1, that is, not likely to happen or most likely to happen. Therefore a and c are not probability. What are the concepts behind this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you mean with "concepts behind this"?

Comment: How can I support my answer using any math concept/"theorem"?

Comment: There's no need for that. You correctly stated that for a probability $p$ we have $0\leq p\leq 1$; that's it, you don't need anything more.

Comment: What would be the concept behind a probability of -0.1? or 1.01?

Comment: Think of it yourself. How can a chance, a likelihood of something be negative. Suppose I flip a 2 rupee coin, then the probability of a 5 rupee coin landing on ground would be $0$, which is utmost, how can it go in the negative direction?

Comment: Copy-paste from your question: $\color\red{\text{The concepts behind this}}$ is that $\color\green{\text{Probability can either be expressed in percentages, decimals, proper fractions or }}$ $\color\green{\text{numbers between 0 to 1, that is, not likely to happen or most likely to happen}}$.

Comment: How do you give color and style to text in LaTeX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Thank you. I found the defining properties of probability which sums up your comments)*

Probability has two defining properties:

1.The probability of any event is a number between 0 and 1, or 0 < P(E) < 1. A P followed by parentheses is the probability of (event E) occurring. Probabilities fall on a scale between 0, or 0%, (impossible) and 1, or 100%, (certain). There is no such thing as a negative probability (less than impossible) or a probability greater than 1 (more certain than certain).

2.The sum of all probabilities of all events equals 1, provided the events are both mutually exclusive and exhaustive. If events are not mutually exclusive, the probabilities would add up to a number greater than 1, and if they were not exhaustive, the sum of probabilities would be less than 1.

Answer (score -1):

You have just given the answer! Probability can be $0$ between it and $1$ or $1$. So a) and c) are the answers. 
Laws in probability state that sum of all probability equals $1$.

Comment: f, of course, is not either.

Comment: it has been edited. it is actually 20%

Comment: I don't know if your probability course started by stating several Axioms of probability (usually four of them). If so, then technically speaking, the answer to your 'why' question would be to see how the idea that a probability is between 0 and 1 (inclusive) follows from the axioms. If no axioms are stated, then 'intuitive' answers such as in your question and some Comments have to suffice.